# Hotlink Protection not working with .htaccess and OpenLiteSpeed and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hotlinking, openlitespeed

I am trying to prevent the hotlinking of images and videos from my website. I have OpenLiteSpeed installed on my server. I added this code on top of the .htaccess file according to the [official guide](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cpanel:enable_hotlink_protection) but it does not prevent hotlinking.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|mp4)$ - [F]
```

Full .htaccess code is below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?\.user\.ini$
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <Files ".user.ini">
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
        </IfModule>
        </Files>
</IfModule>


# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker LOGIN COOKIE start ###
RewriteRule .? - [E="Cache-Vary:wp-postpass_fe3baf7167f747141705df075dacbd93"]
### marker LOGIN COOKIE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31557600
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31557600

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/png A31557600
ExpiresByType image/gif A31557600
ExpiresByType image/webp A31557600

ExpiresByType video/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31557600
ExpiresByType video/webm A31557600

ExpiresByType text/css A31557600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31557600

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31557600
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31557600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A31557600

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# END NON_LSCACHE


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/example.com/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/example.com/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

I have made a free blogspot.com blog to test it. When I embed videos and images from my website to this blog, they are not blocked and are embedded successfully. What changes do I need to make to .htacess to make it work and prevent other sites from embedding my content?

Comment: have you checked this  https://forum.openlitespeed.org/threads/prevent-hotlinking.1021/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked this and this code does not work either

Comment: "That code" from the linked thread doesn't really make sense - it looks like they've mixed up HTTP and HTTPS (and the first `RewriteRule` is nonsense by itself). @qtwrk

Comment: "free blogger blog" - You need to check the Referrer-Policy that site is using and whether you are linking from/to HTTP/HTTPS. It's quite possible the "blogger blog" is blocking the `Referer` entirely. Try removing the first `RewriteCond` (condition) directive. Check the `Referer` HTTP request header your browser is sending after clicking the link.

Comment: I tried removing the first **RewriteCond** but no luck. I also tried [You Want To See If Your Image Can Be Hotlinked](https://altlab.com/hotlinkchecker.php) with both HTTP and HTTPS versions of an image URL from my website.

Comment: "I tried removing the first RewriteCond but no luck." - Hhhmm, that doesn't really make sense, unless the directive is not being processed at all? Try removing both _conditions_ - that should block all image requests for everyone. There's nothing actually wrong with the directives you posted. However, hotlink protection is not particularly reliable as sites can get around it if they so choose.

Comment: "Try removing both conditions". I did that but still the same result. Maybe some other rewrite condition in .htaccess file is overriding?

Comment: But these directives are at the very top and you have just the directives as posted? When you view your site can you see the images? Try adding the `L` flag to the `RewriteRule` directive, ie. `[F,L]` - although this should not be required, since the `L` flag is implied when using `F` (on Apache at least). To clarify, you are using pretty permalinks with WordPress, no `index.php` present in the URL?

Comment: I have just the directives as posted and I can see the images when I view my site. I added the ```L``` flag. I can still embed the images on blogspot.com. I am using post name permalinks e.g. ```https://www.example.com/sample-post/``` and there is no index.php present in the URL.

Comment: If you removed both directives and still not working, please try restarting the webserver to reload the rules. I tried to remove the "RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$", and it works for me.

Comment: ...and clear your browser cache. The fact you can still see your images with those two `RewriteCond` (conditions) removed implies these directives are not even being processed!? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Also try `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` which blocks _everything_. Or `RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [R,L]` (literally use `example.com`, not your own domain) - which redirect _everything_ to `example.com`.

Comment: ```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www\.)?domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```
try this , works on my test